# Is it possible to compare multiple .csv files contents in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a folder containing 10 .csv files and they look like:

```
> df1
  apple Mary car
a     1    1   1
b     2    2   2
c     3    3   3
d     4    4   4
e     5    5   5

> df2
  apple Mary car
a     1    1   1
b     2    2   2
p     4    3   2
d     4    4   4
e     5    5   5

> df3
  phone Jognny car
a     1      1   1
b     2      2   2
c     3      3   3
p     4      3   4
e     5      5   5
i     1      2   3
```

I want to know how "similar" the dfs are. For example, `df1` and `df2` have 100% matches in the colnames but only 80% matches in the rownames. Hence, the two data frame is ~ 87% matches (13/15 data content element).
`df2` and `df3` have only 33% colnames matches...etc Then, `df1` and `df3`...etc

It's something similar to the `cor()`, but there are data frame with different dimensions and colnames... etc

Code for generating data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(apple = 1:5, Mary = 1:5, car = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(apple = c(1, 2, 4, 4, 5), Mary = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5), car = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5)), row.names = c("a", "b", "p", "d", 
"e"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df3)
structure(list(phone = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1), Jognny = c(1, 2, 
3, 3, 5, 2), car = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)), row.names = c("a", "b", 
"c", "p", "e", "i"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the rownames from one data frame that are also rownames of the other:

```
table(colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2))*100/ncol(df1)
#> TRUE 
#>  100 

table(rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2))*100/nrow(df1)
#> FALSE  TRUE 
#>    20    80
```

So your "similarity measure" is how many cells have the same rownames and colnames, divided by how many cells there are. The number of cells is the product of number of rows and columns; the number of cells with matching names is the product of the number of rows and columns with matching names:

```
sum(rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2)) * sum(colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2))
#> [1] 12
nrow(df1)*ncol(df1)
#> [1] 15

100*sum(rownames(df1) %in% rownames(df2)) * sum(colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2))/(nrow(df1)*ncol(df1))
#> [1] 80

compare_names <- function(x, y){
  100*sum(rownames(x) %in% rownames(y)) * sum(colnames(x) %in% colnames(y))/(nrow(x)*ncol(x))
}

compare_names(df1, df2) 
#> [1] 80
```

Note that it's not always symetrical (since `df1` and `df3` have different number of cells, so they don't have the same proportion of matching cell names):

```
compare_names(df1, df3) 
#> [1] 26.66667
compare_names(df3, df1) 
#> [1] 22.22222
```

And of course, here we're only comparing the row and column names, you didn't mention the similarity of values in your question.

---

And as of applying to every combination, the simplest that comes to my mind is with two for loops:

```
all_df <- setNames(list(df1, df2, df3),
                   c("df1", "df2", "df3"))

mat_similarities <- matrix(NA_real_,
              nrow=length(all_df),
              ncol=length(all_df),
              dimnames = list(names(all_df),
                              names(all_df)))

for(i in names(all_df)){
  for(j in names(all_df)){
    mat_similarities[i,j] <- compare_names(all_df[[i]],
                                           all_df[[j]])
  }
}

round(mat_similarities)
#>     df1 df2 df3
#> df1 100  80  27
#> df2  80 100  27
#> df3  22  22 100
```

Comment: Hi, what if I am also interested in the similarity of the value?

Comment: You can use `unlist()` to get all the values, then match them with `%in%` as previously. If you don't just want to match values but also compare relative differences, that becomes more complicated and you'll need to clarify what values you want to compare with what other values.